# Null characters appearing in greasemonkey xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, greasemonkey

I've managed to get an AJAX request working with jQuery but I have to use the built in GM_xmlhttprequest because of cross domain issues.  Any time a string is returned null characters are appended before each character in the string.  Here is the working request in jQuery:

```
var msg = { domain: "BEGIN", command: 'example'};
$.ajax({
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2600',
type: 'GET',
contentType: 'application/json',
data: msg,
success: function(data) {
    console.log('inside');
    $('body').html(data);
},
error: function(xhr, error) { 
    console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
}    
});
```

And the non-working Greasemonkey request:

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:2600/";
var msg = { domain: "BEGIN", command: 'example'};
msg = url+$.param(msg);
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: msg,
    onload: function(response) {
        domains = response.responseText;
        GM_setValue("domainTable", domains);
        alert("data stored");
    }
});
```

I've tried using overideMimeType and setting the response type to text in the headers but I still get the same weird null characters.  I can't paste the string here because it will just ignore the null characters but javascript's charCodeAt spits out a 0 for all the characters at even numbered indexes.  I can obviously delete the null characters or delete every even character in the response each time but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.  I'm assuming its something wrong with the request but I can't for the life of me figure out what.  The server is responding with the exact same response but it's being interpreted differently by the client side.

Comment: Seems like wrong encoding. Is there a way to specify encoding in greasemonkey request? I'm not familiar with it at all.

Comment: *"The server is responding with the exact same response"* - so maybe jQuery is silently trimming those NULL characters? And problem is server-side?